# Appending to CSV file in metro C# application using AppendTextAsync always doubles the output

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am working on a small project for school and I decided to use a metro application for the user interface. I needed a simple way to store data quickly and easily and the only thing I could find that seemed to work was async read/write operations using StorageFolder's and StorageFiles..

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 using the Split-Page metro application template.

The code I am using at this point does exactly what I need it to do, except that it outputs my data to the file twice.

I had the read write operations in its own separate async function passing it the string I needed to output, but this method was easier to post all the content and they both have identical behavior anyway.

When the add user button event goes off, it executes everything down to the .AppendTextAsync call, then appears to jump back to the storageFolder chocFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder line and executes the createFileAsync and AppendTextAsync section again.

This ends up writing the contents of csvString to the file twice every time the function is executed.

If anybody has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

```
   private async void _addUserButtonClicked(object sender,
                                             Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create a Member Object with the added data
        Chocoholics_Anonymous.Common.Member newMember =
            new Chocoholics_Anonymous.Common.Member(Convert.ToInt32(MemberIdBox.Text), 
                                                    MemberNameBox.Text,
                                                    StreetAddressBox.Text,
                                                    CityBox.Text,
                                                    StateBox.Text,
                                                    Convert.ToInt32(ZipBox.Text));
        //Change display information.
        IsAddedBox.Text = "Added to database -" +
                          "\nUserID : " + MemberIdBox.Text +
                          "\nMember : " + MemberNameBox.Text +
                          "\nStreet Address : " + StreetAddressBox.Text +
                          "\nCity : " + CityBox.Text +
                          "\nState : " + StateBox.Text +
                          "\nZip : " + ZipBox.Text;

        //format the string being appended to the file.
        string csvString = MemberIdBox.Text + "," + MemberNameBox.Text +","
                                            + StreetAddressBox.Text + ","
                                            + CityBox.Text + ","
                                            + StateBox.Text + "," 
                                            + ZipBox.Text + "\n";

        StorageFolder chocFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        //Open the file Asynchronusly for writing
        StorageFile chocFile = await chocFolder.CreateFileAsync("ChocAnUserData.csv",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        //Append string to file
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(chocFile, csvString); 

        //Make Display visible.
        IsAddedBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: This is most likely the result of clicking the button twice. Try disabling the button at the top of the handler and re-enabling it at the bottom.

Comment: I tried disabling the button and re-enabling at the end of the call but that made no difference. The function hits await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(chocFile, csvString);
then immediately jumps back to StorageFolder chocFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; and executes everything again.

Comment: Check to see if you registered the button click event handler more than once

Comment: zspencer nailed it. I had the event set to fire when the button was clicked or when it was tapped - I didn't realize clicking would activate both. Thanks!